# override a method but return should be different in C#?

Tags: c#, overriding

I have one interface like below.

```
public interface IUser
{
    List<AppUser> GetAllUser();
}
```

and implementation.

```
public class ObjUser:IUserDao
{
    public virtual List<AppUser> GetAllUser()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

This works fine.

Now i would like inherit **ObjUser** in **CUser** class

```
public class CUser:ObjUser
{
   public override List<ExtAppUser> GetAllUser()
   {
       List <ExtAppUser> extendeduser=new List<ExtAppUser>() ;
       return extenduser;
   }
}
```

And ExtAppUser is inherited from AppUser class.

```
public class ExtAppUser:AppUser
{
     ///// Extend the properties.
}
```

But i get compile error as return type should be same. How to handle in C#? I believe it is possible in Java.

Comment: Your compiler is correct, the return type must be the same. That's the point of an interface, to be a binding contract. If ExtAppUser is derived of AppUser, you can still return the list of base classes, just insert the derived classes.

Comment: @nvoigt: Is it not possible to do like above i am trying to do? Is there is any way to handle above scenario?

Comment: If you want to return a different type, you're not overriding that method, you're defining a new one!

Answer (score 2):

You are asking for a way to corrupt the type system.  A simple example of the failure mode is:

```
public AddUser(IUser users) {
    var newuser = new AppUser("hans');
    users.GetAllUser().Add(newuser);
}
...
var obj = new ObjUser();
foo.AddUser(obj);
```

If this code could execute then the `List<ExtAppUser>` would contain an element of type `AppUser`.  Which is a direct violation of the promise that the list can only contain `ExtAppUser` elements.

This is of course not good.  Type checking exists to *prevent* accidents like this.

This is a general problem called "covariance".  C# version 4 added some support for it, described in [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  That isn't otherwise going to get you anywhere as long as you let IUser.GetAllUser() return a mutable object, you'll have to tone down the return type to a much lesser type like IEnumerable.  Which is okay because nobody can corrupt the object through that interface type, it only permits reading from the underlying object.  Whether that's applicable to your design is impossible to tell.

Comment: I was just checking on interent and found an article. http://www.thebestcsharpprogrammerintheworld.com/blogs/different-return-type-from-a-method-of-a-derived-class.aspx . Will it be good idea to go ahead? Actually my problem starts when i am trying to different return type in derived class (CUser).

Comment: I would take extreme care following advice from someone that claims to be "The Best C# Programmer In The World" and posts non compilable code and says it throws an exception. You'd be better following the MSDN article Hans referenced.